# When does piped command stop?

Tags: command-line, pipe

I struggle to understand the effects of the following command:

```
yes | tee hello | head
```

On my laptop, the number of lines in 'hello' is of the order of 36000, much higher than the 10 lines displayed on standard output.

My questions are:

- When does `yes`, and, more generally, a command in a pipe, stop?
- Why is there a mismatch between the two numbers above. Is it because `tee` does not pass the lines one by one to the next command in the pipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:> yes | strace tee output | head
[...]
read(0, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = 8192
write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = 8192
write(3, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = 8192
read(0, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = 8192
write(1, "y\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\ny\n"..., 8192) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe)
--- SIGPIPE {si_signo=SIGPIPE, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=5202, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGPIPE +++
```

From `man 2 write`:

> EPIPE
>   fd is connected to a pipe or socket whose reading end is closed.  When this happens the writing process will also receive a SIGPIPE  signal.

So the processes die right to left. `head` exits on its own, `tee` gets killed when it tries to write to the pipeline the first time after `head` has exited. The same happens with `yes` after `tee` has died.

`tee` can write to the pipeline until the buffers are full. But it can write as much as it likes to a file. It seems that my version of `tee` writes the same block to `stdout` and the file.

`head` has 8K in its (i.e. the kernel's) read buffer. It reads all of it but prints only the first 10 lines because that's its job.

Comment: I think the 8 k here is the internal buffer used by `tee`, not the kernel's buffer. If we do something like `yes | strace tee output | (sleep 1;  head)`, we'll see that `tee` writes more than that to the pipe before blocking on the write, 64 k on my system (that seems to be the pipe buffer size according to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man7/pipe.7.html)). In the non-sleep case, it's just that `head` gets to run immediately, and closes the pipe.

Comment: The stdout of `tee` is unbuffered.  There are two sets of buffers downstream of it, a kernel buffer that comprises the pipe and the stdin buffering in the standard library of the `head` process.  ikkachu's command line, which I was just about to suggest, demonstrates that the pipe buffer itself can take more than 8KiB.  The 8KiB gulp that `head` takes is the GNU C run-time library filling up the internal buffer in the stdin stream.  (Run this on a BSD, and you'll see the BSD C RTL using different stdin buffer sizes.)

Answer (score 0):

A program which writes to a pipe will receive a **SIGPIPE** signal when the pipe reader terminates and tee(1) will not terminate as long as its standard input stays open.

The head(1) outputs 10 lines by default.

Comment: "tee(1) will not terminate as long as its standard input stays open" – That is not correct; see the `strace` output in my answer. Different versions of `tee` may behave differently, though.