# How does a tool like grep recognize end-of-input when reading from stdin

Tags: stdin

How does a tool like grep know when the end of file is reached, when reading from stdin (like in `foo | grep`)?

The EOF byte could belong to the original file, so it can't rely on that. Does it rely on the fact that the pipe is closed or something else?

Comment: Tangentially related: [What's the last character in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315151/whats-the-last-character-in-a-file)

Comment: ... perhaps you will find this useful as well: [When does piped command stop?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417041/when-does-piped-command-stop)

Comment: There is no "EOF Byte" in Unix/Linux. When the producing process exits, its files are closed. When the consuming process sees the closed file (after consuming the rest of the data) it sets an EOF condition.